# How to check if my PC has a 'Intel 82599 10 Gigabit Ethernet Controller'

Tags: 18.04, intel, nic

How can I check through Ubuntu terminal if Intel@ NIC of my PC has *Intel 82599 10 Gigabit Ethernet Controller*

Comment: Run `lspci` and see.

Comment: @Pilot6 I got the result: Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03). Does it mean that my NIC supports  'Intel 82599 10 Gigabit Ethernet Controller'?

Comment: To be more sure run it as `lspci -nn` that will output the product code, then see it it matches the required one. But it doesn't look like a 10 Gbit one.

Comment: It is a gigabit one I210.

Comment: To find more information about the speeds supported. (As root) run `ip addr` to determine the device name (e.g. `enp3s0f1`) and then using this device name run `ethtool`. For example `ethtool enp3s0f1`.

Comment: `sudo lshw -C network` will show you what speeds your interface can do.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli thnx!

Comment: @Pilot6 thank you for your help, it was helpful

Answer (score 1):

The information you provided indicates you have an [Intel i210](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/series/64399/intel-ethernet-controller-i210-series.html), which is not the [Intel 82599 10 Gigabit Ethernet Controller](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/series/32609/intel-82599-10-gigabit-ethernet-controller.html). They are different hardware.

Comment: After running the command 'sudo lshw -C network' I got the following result    description: Ethernet interface
       product: I210 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: enp5s0
       version: 03
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.6.0-k duplex=full firmware=0. 6-5 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s

Comment: That just confirms what we already knew. Do you want to know more? https://images.app.goo.gl/QAp5nfwoDx2sQcbs5